# About the difference between ambient temperature and rise temperature in pcb design

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

When to use to
Pcb trace width calculator,there are two factors,ambient temp.and rise temp...what is the difference between them?

Comment: Ambient temperature is the local temperature assuming their is no current flowing. Rise temperature is the amount the temperature increases by because of the current.  All tracks have resistance so will dissipate \$ I^2R \$ losses causing the track to get hotter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...But,before i design the pcb i do not know the amount of temperature that will be generate due to current ...so how to know it?

Comment: The thinner the trace the more resistance it has and the hotter it gets.  The trace width calculator takes the rise temperature you can accept to tell you the minimum trace width you need.  Typically I can accept a 10 deg C rise.  Or you can tell it the trace width you have and it will tell you the rise you can expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sizing a trace on a PCB to carry 50 amps](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420988/sizing-a-trace-on-a-pcb-to-carry-50-amps)

Comment: Thank you very much sir...your answer is very acceptable for me to understand..thank you

Comment: I've used this many times  http://saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit/